# Create an instant validation in an Apex form

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

I would like to create validations for page items which are fields of a form. I currently have some validations set up for these page items but they trigger only **after** the form has been submitted. The way I would like the validations to trigger are before the form is submitted so that users get warned of errors with their current field values **before** submitting the form. I think what I am trying to achieve is called "server side validation".

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for 'client side validation'.

There are a few good write-ups on the topic, including a plugin
http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2020/09/building-better-form-in-oracle-apex.html

And a deep dive by one of the APEX devs
https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/05/10/apex-client-side-validation/

The main thing to remember is regardless how to supplement the UX with client side validation, server side validation is a required.

Also note, natively defined validations are also performed prior to page submission, where possible.
https://content.dsp.co.uk/apex/client-side-validations